# Degeneracy in the particle in a circle problem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction

In the quantum [particle in a circle/ring problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_ring), the solution of the Schroedinger equation can be written as:
$$\mathrm{\psi=\frac{1}{\sqrt\pi}cos(n\phi)}$$
and $$\mathrm{\psi=\frac{1}{\sqrt\pi}sin(n\phi)}$$

where n is an integer (0, +1, -1, +2, -2, ...) and $\phi$ is the angular displacement (Obviously, for n=0 the sine function is not a solution).

Energy levels are $$\mathrm{E=\frac{n^2\hbar^2}{2I}}$$ (I is the moment of inertia $\mathrm{mr^2}$)

However, the book Atkins' Physical Chemistry <sup>1</sup>, and also Wikipedia, mentions that the (double) degeneracy of energy for $n>0$ is due to the fact that $n=+1$ and ${n=-1}$ gives the same value of energy as energy only depends on $n^2$.

In my university, our professor solved with the sine and cosine functions, and explained that the degeneracy for $n>0$ happens because both the sin and cosine functions are defined only for $n>0$ so each gives rise to one state. For $n=0$ only the cosine function is defined so there is only one energy state.

How do I solve this confusion?

I realize that the sin and cosine functions are be obtained by summing and subtracting the $e^{in\phi}$ and $e^{-in\phi}$ functions which are used in Atkins' and Wikipedia, and that any linear combination of solutions is also a solution for Schroedinger's Eqn. What I cannot understand is how that shifts the cause of degeneracy from one thing to another.

[When I try to draw the wavefunctions, the sine and cosine explanation makes more intuitive sense, because shifting from sine to cosine changes the phase by $90^\circ$, so the functions are linearly independent and should be different solutions. Whereas in the case of the + and - explanation, changing the sign inverts the sign of the sine function but not the cosine function. The real part of the exponential function remains the same.]

[I am a chemistry undergraduate so I don't have much knowledge of quantum mechanics, and a simple explanation would be more easy to understand for me.]

1. P. Atkins, J. de Paula, J. Keeler, *Atkins' Physical Chemistry*, Oxford University Press, Oxford, 2014, 11th ed., pp 283-285

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you're asking here?  Are you asking for an explanation of the double degeneracy of the energy levels on physical grounds?

Comment: @J.Murray, No I am asking why the form of the solution (sin/cos or e^x) leads to different causes of degeneracy (in the sin/cos case it is two separate solution, in e^x case it is the +ve or -ve nature of quantum number)

Answer (score 2):

I think the confusion is resolved by realizing that these are actually *different* $n$'s.

**Symmetry, conserved quantities, and degeneracy**

We can solve the time-independent Schrödinger equation (TISE) for a particle on a ring of radius $R$ directly, but it's worth thinking about the symmetry of the situation first. Assuming that the ring is oriented so that it's axis is the $z$-axis, the system is rotationally symmetric under a rotation about the $z$-axis, and so the $z$-component of angular momentum $L_z$ is conserved.  This means that the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian (i.e. the solutions to the TISE) can be chosen to *also* be eigenstates of $L_z$. The (non-normalized) eigenstates of $L_z$ are
$$
\psi_m(\phi) = e^{im\phi},
$$
where $m$ is an integer.

As we can see by direction computation, these are also eigenstates of the Hamiltonian, and the corresponding energies are $E_m = m^2$ (up to some constants that you've already noted). Due to the $m^2$ factor, for each $m\neq0$, there are two states with the same energy, and hence we can form linear combinations of them and still get an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian. For instance, we can do
$$
\psi_{\pm}(\phi) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(e^{im\phi}\pm e^{-im\phi}),
$$
which are, of course, the sines and cosines in the OP.

**Quantum numbers**

The number $m$ in $e^{im\phi}$ is the quantum number associated with the angular momentum and is proportional to the angular momentum ($\hbar m$) of this state. Crucially, the linear combinations (the sines and cosines) are *not* eigenstates of the angular momentum operator and hence *cannot* be labeled with this quantum number. Put another way, the sine and cosine states have no well-defined angular momentum.

Instead, from a labeling perspective, we can choose to label the states $\psi_{\pm}(\phi)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(e^{im\phi}\pm e^{-im\phi})$ with the number $n = |m|$, and redefine
$$
\psi_{\pm,n}(\phi) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(e^{in\phi}\pm e^{-in\phi}),
$$
where $n$ is now a non-negative integer. This quantum number (or label) for the state is related to the angular momentum quantum numbers but is not itself an angular momentum quantum number.

**Postscript: the *real* cause of degeneracy**

In the OP, it is mentioned that the "cause" of the degeneracy is different in the two different cases: in one case it's because the sine and cosine, both labeled with the same quantum number $n$ (and hence having the same energy), are linearly independent, whereas for the complex exponentials, the two states have different quantum numbers (e.g. $3$ and $-3$) but happen to be degenerate because of the $m^2$ factor in the energy.

I feel like these mathematical details are red herrings.

The real reason that there is a degeneracy is due to the fact that, physically, there is nothing to distinguish waves that propagate counter-clockwise from waves the propagate clockwise around the ring.  (There are hidden mathematical details here that arise due to the periodic boundary conditions imposed on the wave function, but I feel like the physical intuition is good enough here.) Hence, there must be two states with the same energy at each wavelength. How that manifests mathematically depends on how you decide to solve the problem.

Comment: This clears up most of my confusions. However, you have mentioned that the direction of wave propagation manifests itself differently in the different solutions. I can understand that in case of the exponential functions. Is it also the same in case of sin and cos solution? Because the angular momentum is not well defined in this case, as you noted in the answer. So is it possible to show mathematically (or intuitively) that the sin and cos represent two directions of rotation?

Comment: Roughly speaking, the sines and cosines are standing wave solutions, and the complex exponential are traveling wave solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the solutions $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sin(n\phi)$ for $n = \pm 1, \pm 2,\ldots$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\cos(n\phi)$ for $n = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$, it is better to think in terms of the complex exponentials $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{in\phi}$ for $n = 0,\pm 1,\pm 2, \ldots$ (this is entirely equivalent). Because of the $n^2$ term, the '$\pm$' vanishes and both $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{+im\phi}$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-im\phi}$ have energy 
$$
E_m = \frac{m^2\hbar^2}{2I} 
$$
for $m = 1, 2, \ldots$. This means that, given an energy $E_m = \frac{m^2\hbar^2}{2I}$, it is possible to find *two* states which have this energy (namely $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{\pm im\phi}$). For the case $m=0$, $e^{+i0}=e^{-i0}$ so there is only one state, so there is no degeneracy.

Comment: I am confused about why it is better to use exponentials. Because both forms are solutions to the Schroedinger Eqn., aren't they?